# MySQL date intervals generation

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with MySQL database and I have to generate date intervals for specified period(specified by start and stop date) with specified step(for example one day).

I have written a stored procedure to generate intervals, to create a temporary table and to populate this table with intervals.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE showu(IN start date, IN stop date)
BEGIN

   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE intervals(single_day DATE);
   next_date: LOOP
         IF start>stop THEN
            LEAVE next_date;
         END IF;
         INSERT INTO intervals(single_day) VALUES(start); 
         SET start = DATE_ADD(start, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
   END LOOP next_date;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I want to use this temporary table in join queries. However I faced with a problem. When I call procedure call `showu('2008-01-09', '2010-02-09');` it is executing approximately 30 seconds. The question why it is executing so long? Is it possible to improve it? If this solution is wrong how can I resolve my problem in different way?

Comment: 30 second for that procedure is way too much, but I am not who like the temporary table. Can you give more on why you want to do it, maybe I have some other way of doing it?

Comment: You can. Use application for that. Seriously - DB is not supposed to be used that way. If you still want to use this - just fill constant (not temporary) table with needed data once.

Comment: @SumitGupta Temporary table is the only way I founded. Earlier I used PostgreSQL database. It has generate_series() function that return me set of intervals. This set I can use like a table. I was searching how I can do the same thing in MySQL and the only solution I have founded was temporary table. I need to solve this problem and I accept any suggestion.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I am thinking about this variant(populate appropriate object in application) and I will use it only if there is no other solution. I don't understand your other solution(with constant). Can you show me some examples of how can I use this approach?

Comment: As I understand from your table, you are writing a join, that join on date, and if the Date is there in Temporary table you will show or neglect those record, maybe I wrong, but if you are doing this, then a simple between will do the work, I am just curious in what scenario you need this table...

Comment: @SumitGupta I am using this for report generation. In report I have to show all dates with specified step.For example if date range is '2008-01-09', '2010-03-09' in temporary table will be 3 rows '2008-01-09', '2008-02-09', '2008-03-09'. After this I do left outer join on date column. If no data exists for '2008-02-09' in query result I will have row '2008-02-09' null ... null and this is what I need. I want to bring such rows from the query and not to generate their in application.

Comment: I would rather create usual (not static) table and fill it with dates just once (for next 100 years). Then just use the table instead of creating the temp tables every time you need the report.

Comment: @StanislavL This is a variant, but it has 2 big problems: 1. I don't know exactly value of step(one day or one month or one hour). 2. I will clog my database with not model data. Also I have to keep initialization script in my project, but I don't want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

> 2 big problems: 1. I don't know exactly value of step(one day or one month or one hour).

Create one big table like this once (not temporary):

```
full_date | year | month | day | full_time | hour | minute | is_weekend | whatever
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Create as much indexes as needed and you will have a very performant a powerful swiss knife for all sorts of reports.

**Note**: You might consider not having time and date in the same table. This is just to simplify the example.

Your second problem

> I will clog my database with not model data.

is no problem. Databases are there to hold data. That's it. If you have problems with space or whatever, the solution is to get more space, not to limit your ability to work efficiently.

That being said, here's some examples how to use this table.

You need dates:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
   SELECT full_date AS your_step 
   FROM your_new_swiss_army_knife 
   WHERE `year` = 2012 
   GROUP BY full_date
) dates
LEFT JOIN your_tables_that_you_want_to_build_a_report_on y ON dates.your_step = y.date
```

Same with months:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
   SELECT CONCAT(year, '-', month) AS your_step 
   FROM your_new_swiss_army_knife 
   WHERE full_date BETWEEN this AND that
   GROUP BY year, month
) dates
LEFT JOIN your_tables_that_you_want_to_build_a_report_on y ON dates.your_step = CONCAT(YEAR(y.date), '-', MONTH(y.date))
```

Comment: @mvb13 So, any feedback so far?